# Repeat statement always iterates exactly once

Tags: ti-basic

I'm just starting TI-86 BASIC programming with the following guessing game:

```
:randInt(1,10)→X
:0→A
:Repeat A=X
:Disp "Guess the number"
:Input "between 1 and 10.", A
:End
```

My understanding of the `Repeat` statement is that the block will execute until the condition is true. In my case, I find that the block executes exactly once. That means the value of `A` that the user enters is always the same as the random value of `X`, which I find hard to believe.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me on the TI-84 SE+. Could you post your full code instead of just this excerpt?

Comment: This *is* the full code. The program is supposed to end when the guess is correct. The polish can come later, if at all.

Comment: Huh, that's very strange. Even on the TI-89 the equals operator is used to compare two objects. Maybe try `==`?

Comment: Yes. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34392266/584670).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in the TI-86's version of TI-BASIC can be compared using the `==` operator. So the program becomes

```
:randInt(1,10)→X
:0→A
:Repeat A==X
:Disp "Guess the number"
:Input "between 1 and 10.", A
:End
```

Answer (score 4):

### `=` is "equation-variable assignment", not equality testing

I don't have a TI-86, but I'm pretty sure this is right.

> A less commonly used method of storing a value to a variable is with
>   the "=" operator. The code
>
> `:A=45`
>
> does pretty much the same thing as [the store arrow], except
>   that it makes A an "equation variable" (Which can be used in the
>   equation solver) instead of a "real variable".

[Source](http://ti86world.tripod.com/programming/chapter03.htm)

Since A is being stored into, the expression `A=X` will return the new value of A; that is, X. Because TI-BASIC considers all nonzero numbers to be true, and X is always between 1 and 10, `A=X` assigns A to X and returns a true value, thus stopping the loop.

As OP said, use `==` instead for equality comparison.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I wish there was a less awkward way to compare two variables for equality. I was thinking of using the TI-86 as a distraction-free environment for my son to learn programming, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: `While A/=X` (/= represents the not-equals sign) would also work, right?